# model.xml missing in Using urdf with robot_state_publisher

Tags: urdf, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to follow the [Using urdf with robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher)  tutorial.

The required model.xml file mentioned in turial is missing.
Is there any way it can be obtained?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276685/model.xml-missing-in-using-urdf-with-robot_state_publisher/) by [Anant](https://answers.ros.org/users/26791/anant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `model.xml` file isn't missing, the links to it on that page weren't working anymore (probably related to #q275773).

I've [fixed the links](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher?action=diff&rev2=23&rev1=21), so you should be able to download the file again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1